# Select 2nd DIV CLASS with same name - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I can select the first `class="hm-Login_InputField ">`   fine and pass in user name

```
<div class="hm-Login ">
    <div class="hm-Login_UserNameWrapper ">
        <input type="text" class="hm-Login_InputField ">
        <div class="hm-Login_InputText ">Join</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ">
        <input type="text" class="hm-Login_InputField ">
        <input type="password" class="hm-Login_InputField Hidden ">
        <button tabindex="0" class="hm-Login_LoginBtn ">GO</button>
        <div class="hm-Login_InputText ">Lost Login?</div>
    </div>
</div>

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("hm-Login_InputField")
elem.click()
elem.send_keys("xxxxx")
```

I've tired copying the Xpath for the 2nd text input / password textbox. with inconstant results, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/input[2]
```

How can I select the 2nd  `class="hm-Login_InputField`?  text input / password textbox?

Do I need a relative Xpath? How is this derived?

I've tried:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("hm-Login_InputField Hidden ")
elem.click()
elem.send_keys("xxxxx")
```

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".hm-Login_InputField Hidden "}
>     (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if any frame is present if yes then you need to switch to frame first.

Also add wait first like explict wait like `visibilityOfElementLocated` or `presenceOfElementLocated`

try below xpath as well:

```
//input[@type='password']
```

OR

```
//div[@class='hm-Login ']//div[@class='hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ']//input[@type='password']
```

Comment: elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ']//input[@type='text']")
elem.click()
elem.clear()          

im now able to select the box , however now I can't .sendkeys(). and im getting   ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

I've tried adding in a 

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ']//input[@type='text']"))).click()

and.   driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

both unsuccessful...


this is one the www.bet365.com.au website..if you want to try.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if your issue ask in question resolve... for new issue kindly create an another question.. thats how stack works and its policy stated

Answer (score 1):

This xpath was successful:

```
Elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(**"//div[@class='hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ']//input[@type='text']")** 
elem.click() 
elem.clear()
```

I'm now able to select the box.

Thanks @Shubham Jain

Answer (score 0):

If it works sometimes that may be because of an element loading slower. Try to add `time.sleep(2)` before you call the second element and see if it works.
Also instead of `driver.find_element_by_class_name("hm-Login_InputField Hidden ")` you can use `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("hm-Login_InputField")` and this will return all the elements with class `"hm-Login_InputField"`. Then `elem[0]` will be your first input `elem[1]` the second and goes on and on.